# Error on enabling touchscreen in QT

Tags: attributes, touch, qt5

I want to enable touchscreen in QT, so I gave:

```
ui->pushButton->setsetAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents,true);
```

but it shows the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'QPushButton::setAttribute(bool)'
>            ui->pushButton->setAttribute((Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents,true));
>                                                                    ^

Comment: Your code snippet contains a typo ("setset") and clearly does not even match the compiler error. That is misleading those that are trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the superfluous parentheses:

```
ui->pushButton->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents,true);
```

vs.

```
ui->pushButton->setAttribute((Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents,true));
```

Comment: Sorry! While typing here,I done mistake but in computer I gvn properly but showing error, I mentioned that also.

Comment: Not according to the compiler. Look at the error message.

Comment: Tnx for response,it is showing no such function, how can i resolve it?

Comment: Please update the question with an exact copy-paste of your code and the resulting error message.